# Sharepoint 2010 Edit Redirect Page

Tags: redirect, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Using SharePoint 2010. I have created a page with an html redirect put in a content editor (the redirect template was not working properly). I need to make an edit to the redirect timer but the page redirects me even when going in checked-out as an editor and I don't have enough time to get into the source. Is there a way to get into the page and view the HTML Source of the content editor without being redirected or stop the redirect as an editor?

Comment: This question is off-topic here, use [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint Designer to edit the page and modify the contents of the Content Editor Web Part in code view.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Codingo, but I believe this does answer the question, and is not providing a critique or requesting clarification. Using SharePoint Designer to edit the page will circumvent the problem that TimeStamp12 is encountering-- namely, that his or her JavaScript redirect is causing the browser to navigate away from the page before it can be edited.